# Movement with easing over a period of time

Tags: javascript, game-physics, easing

I'm trying to move an object a certain distance and have it ease into and out of its motion. I have this:

`this.x/y` is the end point of the object
`moveable` is the object
`this.duration` is the amount of frames it takes for the movement to complete
`this.time` is the amount of frames that have passed since the movement started

```
moveable.x += 
    (Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * (this.time/this.duration) + Math.PI)/2 + .5) * ((this.x - moveable.x) / (this.duration - this.time)) * Math.PI;

moveable.y += 
    (Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * (this.time/this.duration) + Math.PI)/2 + .5) * ((this.y - moveable.y) / (this.duration - this.time)) * Math.PI;
```

This gets the object pretty close to where it needs to go but not quite to the right place. I'm not quite sure what kind of equation I should be using. Any help?

PS - I'd rather not do this with speed and acceleration for various reasons that I wont go into.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS animations and transitions, but if we stick with your javascript (in theory):

**to ease in then ease out:**

Consider the function ( cos( π(x+1) )+1 ) / 2. This eases from 0 to 1 as x goes from 0 to 1.
I'm redefining `moveable` instead of `+=` adding onto it.

```
var init=[x:moveable.x , y:moveable.y] // initial position
...
moveable.x = 
( Math.cos( Math.PI*(this.time/this.duration+1) )+1 )/2 //goes from 0 to 1
    * (this.x - init.x) //total difference in position (now goes from 0 to dx)
    + init.x // goes from init.x to this.x
```

Then you can repeat for `y`.